# What's the difference between Graphics.clearRect and Graphics.drawRect?

Tags: java, swing, background

I found a rendering bug in some code and have found a workaround, but I would like to know why I am getting different behaviour. In the old code, the background would (sometimes) be rendered as white, despite while debugging `getBackground()` would return the correct colour.

Old code:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
  // Stuff

  g.setColor(getBackground());
  g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height); // Obviously wrong.

  // More stuff
}
```

New code:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
  // Stuff

  g.setColor(getBackground());
  g.drawRect(0, 0, width, height); // Correct usage with 'setColor' call.

  // More stuff
}
```

As I put in the code, it is obvious that `setColor(getBackground())` has no effect on the `clearRect(...)` call. Yet I would assume that calling `clearRect(...)` and calling `setColor(getBackground())` followed by `drawRect(...)` would be semantically the same.

I have also considered the opaqueness property, but the parent lightweight components and ancestor heavyweight component all use the same background colour, and it is quite obvious that this component is the one with the incorrect behaviour (it is one of 8 of the same type of component owned by its parent - yet only the ones that get to this section of code have a problem).

I am using JDK 1.6.0_07 (for business reasons of course) if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the information from the JavaDocs -

> Clears the specified rectangle by filling it with the background color of the current drawing surface. This operation does not use the current paint mode.
>
> Beginning with Java 1.1, the background color of offscreen images may be system dependent. Applications should use setColor followed by fillRect to ensure that an offscreen image is cleared to a specific color.

As this implies, clearRect is system dependent and the value of getBackground() is not taken into account.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. The issue did only occur sometimes when something was rendered over the top of the component for a split second. It's strange that it never recovered once it was considered 'on screen' again though. Well, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The difference is this :

- if you use the graphics method fillRect() you can't erase the color by using drawRect() over the same recatngle specified in pixels.
- but if you use the graphics method fillRect() then clear it with clearRect() and after that drawRect(); you reach a satisfaction and a conclusion.